# Send gmail less secure apps off?

Tags: java, email, gmail

I know that a lot of people has asked this but I really need to explain my case. I have a software made with java where my clients emit legal documents and when they finish, the program send a mail to their clients. The problem is that sometimes they send to many mails that google blocks the connections even with the less secure apps on. So I need a way to make this work, I need to find the way for google not to block the connections.

There is a way? I would be really greatfull with you guys if you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it with Java mail if that's what you're using. You will need to use Google's API to send mail with less secure apps off.

Read this:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2

Comment: I read something about that api, but I didn't knew if that will work on my case, every client has their **own** gmail account

Comment: Yes, the API should allow them to log in with their own account via Google's login